# C++ map from std::pair to some internal class

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11, dictionary

**SET UP**

```
#include<utility> // I actually use precompiled headers 
#include<map>
...SOME CODE...
namespace{
... SOME CODE...
/*Line 278*/ std::map<std::pair<int,int>,SmartPointer<A>> myMap;
/*Line 279*/ myMap.at(std::make_pair(1,1));
}
```

SmartPointer is what is says - a class that wraps other classes with smart pointers for automatic heap memory management.

What happens is that when I try to compile this I get a whole bunch of errors:

```
cpp(279): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '.'
cpp(279): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not 
support default-int
cpp(279): error C2371: '`anonymous-namespace'::map' : 
redefinition; different basic types
cpp(278) : see declaration of '`anonymous-namespace'::map'
```

Lines 278 and 279 are the code lines above.

map is in an anonymous-namespace as can be seen. I suspect that this is because maps internally aren't configured to accept non-standard types as values.

This is all happening in VS 2010 + I am also using C++11.

**QUESTION**

Why do I get these compilation errors and how to fix them ?

**PROGRESS**

The `>>` is not the issue - when I comment out the second line the file compiles without complaining (both with `>>` and `> >`).

I reduced the code to this - to see where the errors might be coming from - and I get the following set of compilation errors:

code:

```
std::map < int, int > myMap;
myMap[3] = 4;
```

errors:

```
cpp(279): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not 
support default-int
cpp(279): error C2373: 'myMap' : redefinition; different type modifiers
cpp(278) : see declaration of 'myMap'
cpp(279): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'int [3]'
There are no conversions to array types, although there are conversions 
to references or pointers to arrays
```

**ANSWER**

@Casey

As suggested by Casey, I can't put `myMap.at(..)` at namespace scope - I put it in a function scope and it got fixed.

Comment: That's because you are missing a space between `>` and `>`: `std::map<std::pair<int,int>,SmartPointer<A>/*HERE*/ > map;`

Comment: The compiler is probably parsing >> as the operator.

Comment: It isn't ! it compiles just fine with `>>`, but I changed it anyway and the error persists.

Comment: You can't just put `map.at(...)` at namespace scope, it needs to be inside a function.

Comment: It just compiled - point taken

Answer (score 0):

Just don't reuse standard library names such as `map` for variable names. Call it *something* meaningful, and it will also remove the conflict between type and variable.

Also, you forgot to `#include <utility>` to bring in `std::pair`.

Comment: I use precompiled headers (`stdafx`, which has `#include<utility>` inside) and I renamed my variable `map` for clarity - internally it is called something else as I did not want to reveal more information about my implementation.

Comment: However, point taken - I will rename my posted source code for clarity  when people read it

Answer (score 0):

you have a name clash:

```
std::map<std::pair<int,int>,SmartPointer<A>> map;
```

the name `map` is the type. You cannot use type names as variable names. Something like

```
std::map<std::pair<int,int>,SmartPointer<A>> myMapThatHasAUsefullName;
```

should fix it.

Comment: Sorry for that - I internally use a different name, now I renamed the variable to `myMap` for clarity. The problem wasn't in that though - it was because I couldn't call `myMap.at(..)` at namespace-level.